# AWS: Route traffic from Site-To-Site VPN --> Specific Subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-networking, aws-site-to-site, aws-route-table

Inside a vpc I have 8 subnets (4 in each AZ) connected to 100 VMs.

I have a Site-To-Site **vpn** setup in AWS for an external customer. The goal is to allow only one VM is to be accessible to the external customer.

There is a **vpg** associated with the **vpc**. Security Group configurations have created a number of pathways to other VMs.

I have created a new Subnet and I want to route the traffic from the VPN **only** to this new **SubNet**.

I thought this would be done with a **Route Table**, but I do not cannot see how to do this.

I created a new subnet and Route Table. I associated the new subnet with the new RT. I created a new route:

[image]

I got the following error:

```
The destination CIDR block 192.168.11.0/24 is equal to or more specific than one of this VPC's CIDR blocks. This route can target only an interface or an instance.
Goal:
```

[image]

Comment: When traffic comes to VGW from an external custormer, VGW refer to the route table of VPC. So just confirm the route table of VPC has `local` for cidr range of Subnet you want to route. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Route_Tables.html

Comment: I have multiple routeTables. They all come with a default of vpc.cidr_range : local. How am I supposed to keep traffic from going to other subnets ?

Comment: My answer is still the same. But please let me confirm. What are CIDR ranges of three subnets in your img above? To which the multiple route tables attached?

Comment: 192.168.0.1 -  192.168.0.254; Existing route tables are associated with all. If I make a new RT, I still cannot associate 192.168.11.0/24<-->vpg.